# как работает alignas в с++?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, выравнивание, препроцессор

Я хочу защитить несколько атомарных переменных от фолс шеринга, как я понимаю, это можно сделать, указав чтоб переменные занимали одну строку кеша.

Я нашел, что этого можно добиться с помощью alignas(размер кеш линии)

```
alignas(64) std::atmic<int> a1;
alignas(64) std::atmic<int> a2;
```

Но я не совсем понимаю, что значит это выравнивание, это явно указывает, что в кеш переменная будет загружаться с битами заполнения? Если взять sizeof то размер переменной не изменится.В ассемблере тоже нет изменений, если компилировать с выравниванием и без

Иными словами, конечный вопрос, как работает выравнивание?

Comment: Выравнивание означает, что адрес объекта должен быть кратен значению выравнивания.

Comment: `указав чтоб переменные занимали одну строку кеша` Наоборот же. Переменные должны занимать разные строки кеша. Каждая строка кеша процессора хранит выровненный `N`-байтный (обычно `64`) фрагмент оперативной памяти. Выровненный — значит адрес первого байта фрагмента кратен длине строки. Без дополнительного выравнивания, две переменные могут оказаться очень близко друг к другу в оперативной памяти, и весьма вероятно попадут в одну строку кеша. Когда два ядра процессора модифицируют данные в одной строке кеша, то это медленнее, чем если бы они модифицировали разные строки.

Comment: Если переменным задать дополнительное выравнивнивание, то их адреса окажутся достаточно далеко, чтобы с большой вероятностью попасть в разные строки кеша.